# Position an element over another one's padding

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kn7g54j1/2/

How do I position the tooltip on top of it's parent's padding? Is that even possible?

Here's my snippet:

```css
    span {
  width: 100px;
}
.input-group {
  padding-right: 20px;
}  
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" value="firstname" />
  <div class='tooltip placeholder'>^</div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" value="lastname" />
</div>
```

And this is what the code outputs:

[image: output]

Comment: @GCyrillus, updated based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I position the tooltip on top of it's parent's padding? Is that even possible?

It is definitely possible.

You have the right idea with the `position: absolute`. The main point is removing the tooltip from the document flow, otherwise, it will be in the content area of the parent element, instead of over the parent's padding.

Try it here:

```css
.input-group {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}  

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
  <div class='tooltip placeholder'>^</div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>
```

**Edit:** I have refactored your code as nesting block elements in `<span>` isn't good practice.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was missing. Setting the parent `.input-group` to relative. And then being able to position the `.tooltip` relative to it's parent. Thanks. I used `display: inline` instead of `float: left` because it serves my purpose better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set negative margin to make this work?

For example

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: yes I could. And that works, but doesn't really serve my purpose. it would be a lot of manual pixel pushing, especially if I have many of these inputs each with its own tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#ab8e7d11a9e2412863824bf0e3176caf

I might be wrong, but last I checked embedding a DIV inside of a SPAN element is not [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org)

First off a `DIV` element by default is [display block](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/). Meaning it behaves like a paragraph (minus the padding) and always is added on a new line. So instead of using a `DIV` use a SPAN element which is [display inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Remember [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Now as for your question...

> How do I position the tooltip on top of it's parent's padding?

You can do this using [position absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), [position fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), or [position relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). (In your case [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) or [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) would be what you want to use)

Here's a simple example. (I'm using [Normalize CSS Reset](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) so the UI looks the same on all browsers.)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="input-group">
  <input type="text" value="firstname">
  <span class="tooltip placeholder">^</span>
</span>
<span class="input-group">
  <input type="text" value="lastname">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:relative along with z-index to get your tooltip anywhere and over any padding or element you want..

I have implemented your code on a seperate html as i didn't have your html structure.

You can change the .topltip{top:__px} to adjust your tooltip vertically according to your need.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            span {
              width: 100px;
            }
            .input-group {
              padding-right: 20px;
            }  
            .tooltip {
              position: relative;
              top: -10px;
              display: table-cell;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            .input-group{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="input-group">

          <input type="text" value="firstname" />

          <div class='tooltip placeholder'>^</div>

        </span>

        <span class="input-group">
          <input type="text" value="lastname" />
        </span>

    </body>
</html>
```